How can I print an array in assembly using the Intel 8088 processor?
How can I print an array (or table) of numbers using only the instructions available in the Intel-8088? I am using VonSim to simulate the whole thing.
To print a single number using the interruption 7 which prints only characters, I have something like this:
D_ZERO EQU 48 ; ASCII code for 0

org 1000H

char  db ?
number db 4

org 2000h

mov ah, number
add ah, D_ZERO
mov char, ah
mov al, 1
mov bx, offset char
int 7
int 0
end

But I need a a loop or something that allows me to print for example: table1 db 1, 2, 3:
D_ZERO EQU 48 ; ASCII code for 0

org 1000H

char   db ?
table1 db 1, 2, 3
size   3

org 3000h

print_table:
    <CODE TO PRINT THE TABLE>
    .
    .
    .
    int   7
    jnz   print_table
    ret

org 2000h

mov  ah, table1
call print_table
int  0
end


Related: Displaying numbers with DOS for how to print a single integer as a string.  If all your numbers are single-digit (0-9), you can simplify it to adding '0' (30h) to get the ASCII code for the digit character.  For looping over the array, you want a pointer in a register like SI, and inc si / mov ah, [si] then use your char-printing code.  Or modify the array by adding '0' to every element, then use that write-buffer system call to write the whole array as a single string.  (I assume al=1 is a count?)

I think I found the answer to my own question.
org 1000H

table1 db 1, 2, 3
end_t1   db "F"; The value is not important here. We need the address instead.
aux    db ?; An auxiliary variable to store the converted ASCII value.

org 3000h

; Prints any table that has been moved to register bx.
print_table:
    mov dx, bx; Using dx as auxiliar register
    mov ah, [bx]
    add ah, 48; Converts to ASCII by adding 48 (30h - zero value in ASCII)
    mov aux, ah
    mov al, 1
    mov bx, offset aux
    int 7; Prints the character in screen
    mov bx, dx; Restores bx to the original value
    inc bx
    cmp bx, offset end_t1; Checks if we have reached the end of the table
    jnz print_table; Loops back if not to print the next character in the table
    ret

org 2000H

mov  bx, offset table1
call print_table

int 0
end

The trick here is to use the DX register to temporary store the initial value of BX.
The problem I was facing was that BX is altered later on in the execution of the code by the aux variable. This one is used to store the result of adding the ascii value of zero so we can get the number's ascii value.
Without DX and using only the BX, the first character of the table is printed correctly, but not the other as we already know that BX has been modified by other values.

You could use si or di as the array pointer; those work in addressing modes, too.  So you can just inc si and mov ah, [si], etc.
